# Molecular Logic GATE

Tags: genetics, synthetic-biology

Currently either PET-Fluorophore or FRET is used as output of the molecular/DNA-based logic gate. Likewise, in a logic gate, lets say YES GATE, you provide an input to the logic gate and in return you got fluorescence. Please help me understand what other transfer method can be used as the output. I want to develop a complex system i.e. connect multiple logic gates with each other which, definitely, cannot happen if molecular logic gate would return output such as fluorescence, can any other method be used?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to be more specific than this.